# converting rgb numpy image to list of rgb and corresponding index values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy matrix representing rgb image. Its shape is (n,m,3) with n rows, m columns and 3 channels. I want to convert it to list of rgb values along with corresponding indeces.

I can convert to list of rgb values but I am trying to have row and col indeces alongside as well.

We can do something like this for rgb values only.

`flat_image = np.reshape(image, [-1,3]) # shape = [mxn, 3]`

After also adding row and column number, the shape should be [mxn, 3+2]

so first three columns in the flat image represent rgb, fourth column represents row number from the original image array and fifth column represent col number from the original imagem array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to construct the row/column indices and then concatenate that with your `flat_image`

```
indices = np.indices(image.shape[:-1])

result = np.concatenate([flat_image, indices], axis=-1)
```

Comment: I see. Can it be directly this np.array(np.ndindex(*image.shape))

Comment: actually this is also including channel number.

Comment: It should be like this: indices = np.array(list(np.ndindex(image.shape[0],image.shape[1]))) to not have the channel numbers

Comment: @Leo, sorry about the shape issue! I've updated the answer to fix that bug and to also use `numpy.indices` instead of `numpy.ndindex` so that you don't have to use the awkward `np.array(list(..))`.